# Swift - loading data into an array of structures

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

How do I load data into an array of structures in Swift?

What is the required syntax in the following?

```
struct TEST {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0
}

var test: [TEST] = []

// Data to load:
// .a   1,2,3
// .b   4,5,6
// .c   7,8,9
```

**UPDATE 1**

@pacification Sorry for the delay in responding. Based on your Update 1, I have this code, which runs with no errors:

```
struct TEST {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
}

var a: [Int] = [1,2,3]
var b: [Int] = [4,5,6]
var c: [Int] = [7,8,9]

let test: [TEST]

for (index, _) in a.enumerate() {
    TEST(a: a[index], b: b[index], c: c[index])
}
```

However, I cannot see how to store the values in the 'test' array. What am I missing?

Comment: what is the type of data to load? array, dict, set, array of dicts, dict of arrays etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
struct Test {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var c = 0
}


var test: [Test] = [
    Test(a: 1, b: 4, c: 7),
    Test(a: 2, b: 5, c: 8),
    Test(a: 3, b: 6, c: 9)
]
```

Pay attention, that `struct`s have default `init` method ([more info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)), so you don't need create it.

---

**UPDATE**

> I want to initialize the 'test' structure array with a length of 200

You can do that like this:

```
var test: [Test] = Array(count: 200, repeatedValue: Test())
```

> I want to enter the data for 'a', 'b' and 'c' using this syntax:
>   [1,2,3, ...] Is this possible?

Ahm. What `type` of `a`, `b` or `c` should be in your case? `Array`?

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
// Data to load:
// .a   1,2,3
// .b   4,5,6
// .c   7,8,9
```

So, if you are sure that `a`, `b` and `c` same length arrays you can do like this:

```
for (index, _) in a.enumerate() {
    Test(a: a[index], b: b[index], c: [index])
}
```

And all your data will be stored.

Comment: Thanks to 芮星晨, ishdeep and pacification for your similar answers. That  syntax works, but it is still not quite what I need. I want to initialize the 'test' structure array with a length of 200. I want to enter the data for 'a', 'b' and 'c' using this syntax: [1,2,3, ...]  Is this possible?

Comment: The data type is Int. I have working test code where I am declaring and loading three separate arrays, using this syntax:   var a: [Int] = [1,2,3, ...]

Comment: I would prefer to have these three arrays combined into one structure,

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use this

```
struct test{
        var a:Int
        var b:Int
        var c:Int
        init(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int){
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
        }
    }

func addSomeData(){
        var array:[test] = []
        array.append(test(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3))
        array.append(test(a: 4, b: 5, c: 6))
        array.append(test(a: 7, b: 8, c: 9))
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to write such `init`s for structs, because they are provided by the compiler automatically (that's also noted in @pacification's answer).

Answer (score 0):

What i interpret from your question is you want to make an array object for a structure and store data in it.
Here is an example that might help you.

```
struct TableData{
let a : Int
let b : Int
let c : Int }
```

Where ever you wish to access the struct array you will have to declare that array in that class.

```
var details = [TableData]()
```

Now adding data to the array depends on how you want store the data in the struct array. So i will tell you how to access each element of the array.

First you create a struct object that will store one set of struct details at a time.

```
let data = Tabledata(a:1,b:4,c:7)
details.append(data)
```

Ofc this will just a static allocation, i would suggest you use a loop to keep getting the details and adding them to the table array.

```
for i..in 3{
     let data = Tabledata(a:some value,b:some value,c:some value)
     details.append(data)
            }
```

Assuming you know about loops and concept of dictionaries you can get the values for some value and this will create 3 entries in the details array.

Let me know if it helps or if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be semantics?
Structures in Swift are general purpose types (like classes). They are fairly similar but have relevant differences e.g. structures are value types.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Maybe you are looking for a Dictionary (key - value data)?

```
    var arryOfDictionaries = [
      ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3],
      ["a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6],
      ["a": 7, "b": 8, "c": 9]
    ]

    // Iterate of the array
    for dict in arryOfDictionaries {
      print(dict["a"]) // 1 4 7
      print(dict["b"]) // 2 5 8
    }

    // Add more "rows"
    var oneMore = ["a": 10, "b": 11, "c": 13]
    oneMore["c"] = 12
    arryOfDictionaries.append(oneMore) // Added [10, 11, 12]
```

If not then @pacification answer is a cleanest way to use structs.
Also remember that `Structures` are not reference types like classes so you are not using instances, but rather copied values (as when using `Int` or `Strings`)

If you are not looking for an array of dictionaries as my example above suggest, a simple static class is also a good candidate.

Just my gut feeling, but your example above does not look like a typical use case for structs.